# Load text from html form to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying...(I know very trying for all you guys lol) no but seriously I am trying to pass the text from a form to a div, which then other scripts change the font and the colour of the text. Here is the code I have tried so far and a link to the jsfiddle. I just can't get it to work!

Similar questions have been asked but none I can find where other scripts then need to run on that inputted text once it has been inputted.

http://jsfiddle.net/p802ektq/

The Div:

```
<div class="rightBottom selectcolor" style = "position: absolute; left: 750; top: 330;"     id="changeMe"></div>
```

The HTML form:

```
<form>
 Address <input type="text" name="add"><br>
 <input id="copy" type="button" value="copy">
 </form>
```

The Java:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#copy').click(function(){  
    $('#changeMe').val($('#add').val() );
  });
});
```

Comment: Just change `.val(`, on `#changeMe`, to `.text(`.

Comment: hmmm didn't work unfortunately but thank you for the response my friend i will have to keep trying!

Comment: Well, you could do as it is on this version of fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p802ektq/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/p802ektq/1/)

First let's remember one thing:

```
name = name
. = class
# = id
```

you *cannot* go for `#add` if you don't have any in your Document. So let's add some:

```
<input id="add" name="add" type="text">
```

Now, if you want to insert some text String into a `<div>` (*#changeMe*) element, what you want is `.text()` or `.html()` (not `.val()` !).

```
$(function() { // d. ready
  $('#copy').click(function( event ){  
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent browser default behavior on form button
    $('#changeMe').text( $('#add').val() );
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and the explanation. Its really handy to know were I am going wrong. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work still so I may have some other conflict in the code somewhere ..Although curiously it doesn't work in the jsfiddle either

Comment: @user3323647 you should check **my** jsFiddle example and the options I've used in the left panel.

Comment: My apologies Roko I didn't even spot that on there.. thats me being blind I have opened it and it works in query. Thankyou again! if you don't teach already you should!

Comment: @user3323647 I have some 2y experience but not doing that currently :) thanks for the heads-up and happy coding!

Comment: Roko C do you have an email address? I have a proposal for you